# Including external JS files in Angular project after using Grunt (via Yeoman)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, google-places-api, yeoman

This is problem I've run into lately. I'm building an Angular project and using Grunt as part of my workflow to minify my JavaScript files. Here's a snippet from my index.html file (I used Yeoman to scaffold out the project):

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<!-- more bower component scripts -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/someCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/anotherCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/someSvc.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/anotherSvc.js"></script>
<!-- Below is the issue -->
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/autocomplete.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Basically, the second to last script is using Google's Autocomplete API and my autocomplete.js directive depends on variables that get exposed by Google Autocomplete. This works perfectly fine before I run grunt --force. But after running grunt --force, all my JS files are minified and compiled together and this is what's causing my problem.

I confirmed this by grabbing the script from "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false" and saving the results into a temporary JavaScript file, and replacing the call to Google's API with this new temporary file. And this works but its a hack and won't be sustainable when Google modifies any of the code (which happens often).

Therefore, my question is whether there's a way for me to include the following script tag:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

in my index.html and not have grunt include it in the minification process? Any help would be greatly appreciated since I'm also fairly new to using Grunt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's causing you problems, why not exceptionally exclude this one script reference outside of the build tags and just call it as is from your index.html?

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/someCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/anotherCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/someSvc.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/anotherSvc.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/autocomplete.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The end result would be 3 js references in your html: the API lib, your vendor.js and script.js. Something like this:

```
<script src="scripts/vendor.d3a1cfb5.js"></script> 
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script> 
<script src="scripts/scripts.ad4decc0.js"></script>
```

Not a major disaster, right?

Incidentally, all this type of stuff is exactly why I switched to Brunch. Never looked back since.

Comment: Are you saying that basically after running grunt --force, just manually include that one script tag in the "grunted" version of index.html?

Comment: No, include that tag in your original file before you compile, just outside of the build tags. I edited my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This solved my problem - really thought to move the files outside of the grunt scripts :/

Comment: ^ meant to say "really *never* thought"